# CAST HEX as DATATIME - how to get date?

Tags: php, sql-server, datetime, casting, hex

I have a problem with processing a SQL Server database dump in PHP.

I have one column called `datatime` with values like :

```
0x0000a0af00d7f2eb
```

I need to extract, in PHP, the date and time values of this column.  I don't have SQL Server available so I can't use the obvious solution of `CAST(0x0000a0af00d7f2eb AS datetime)`.

Someone has told me that this hex: `0000a0af00d7f2eb` is created by 4 bytes of date and 4 bytes of time.

So I know that:

When I will change `0000a0af` (first 4 bytes) to decimal I will get number of days from 1900. That works fine.

But when I'm trying to change last the 4 bytes (so there should be time) : `00d7f2eb` to decimal I'm getting something which I can't understand. It should be a time from midnight in milliseconds and sometimes this value is ~3 times lower.

Could anyone help in converting `0000a0af00d7f2eb` to date? I know that time is between 5 AM and 11 PM, and the day is in last week.

Comment: did u try  select CAST(0x0000a0af00d7f2eb AS datetime) ? it gives the output  2012-08-16 13:06:14.757, is that what you are  looking for?

Comment: Maybe not a full duplicate but might also help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143259/what-is-the-internal-representation-of-datetime-in-sql-server

Comment: @rene actually, i think this is an exact duplicate: OP needs to know internal representation of datetime so that they can convert without using SQL Server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [linked article](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/2004/datetime-datatype/) in the other question linked to by Rene, SQL Server stores 3.33 millisecond intervals in the second set of 4 bytes, not milliseconds.  So if you're calculating with milliseconds, you will indeed be getting a time about 1/3 of what it should be.  Using your example, let's start by converting to decimal

> 00d7f2eb -> 14152427 3.3ms intervals

Now multiply out by 3.3 to convert to milliseconds, and divide by 1000 to get seconds

> 14152427 * 3.3 / 1000 ~ 47127.58

So this represents about 47 thousand seconds after midnight.  Dividing by 3600 seconds in an hour

> 47127.58 / 3600 ~ 13.091

So this represents a time of about 13.1 hours after midnight, which agrees with the result of the cast done in SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

```
select CAST(0x0000a0af00d7f2eb AS datetime) as t
```

is working fine for me. and it returns 'August, 16 2012 13:06:14-0700'.

Comment: If you are not getting this or expecting some other result please provide more information(server version or sample hex value and corresponding date).

Comment: Yes, it's working great, but I need to do it on php script ( I have var "CAST(0x..... AS datetime) in PHP and I need to get date. I don't have mssql server so I can't make select.