# Date parsing from string to DateTime in c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, datetime

I am exporting date values("24/11/2016") from excel file to SQL database table in C#.NET. I am using the following code into my function to parse the date values from string to Datetime. But it is not working. I tried to debug it but when it comes on that line, it's terminating. Anybody know what is the problem.

```
var date = row["Date"].ToString();

DateTime dates;    
string format = "MM-dd-yyyy";

if (!DateTime.TryParseExact(date, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dates))
{ 
  continue;
}                           
else
{
   dates = DateTime.Parse(date); //terminating at this line
}
```

Comment: I am curious why there are 2 parsing commands?  If the TryParse fails, why do you think Parse will succeed?

Comment: thanks for correcting me. But the actual problem is in parsing string values into Datetime.

Answer (score 6):

Your format should be `dd-MM-yyyy` as you have `24/11/2016` as date, you can learn more about string formats in this MSDN article [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx)

*Change*

```
string format = "MM-dd-yyyy";
```

*To*

```
string format = "dd-MM-yyyy";
```

**Edit** based on comments by OP - Storing formatted date in SQL server

The DateTime is stored in a SQL server in standard format that is not in fact the presentation format we see like "dd-MM-yyy". This article [Solving the Datetime Mystery](http://sqlmag.com/sql-server/solving-datetime-mystery) explains the internal SQL server format.

Excerpt from [Solving the Datetime Mystery](http://sqlmag.com/sql-server/solving-datetime-mystery)

> So how does SQL Server internally store the dates? It uses 8 bytes to
>   store a datetime value—the first 4 for the date and the second 4 for
>   the time. SQL Server can interpret both sets of 4 bytes as integers.
>   For the date portion, the value SQL Server stores is the number of
>   days before or after a base date of January 1, 1900. Because of this
>   storage protocol, SQL Server assumed the date of January 1, 1900, when
>   I didn't supply the date in my first example. SQL Server internally
>   stored a value of 0. A negative number represents a date earlier than
>   January 1, 1900.
>
> SQL Server stores the second integer for the time as the number of
>   clock ticks after midnight. A second contains 300 ticks, so a tick
>   equals 3.3 milliseconds (ms). You can see the values for days and
>   clock ticks by converting a datetime value to a binary(8) value and
>   using the substring function to extract each set of 4 bytes. The code
>   in Figure 3 then converts each set of 4 bytes into an integer.

Comment: Appreciation for the upvoters:  take a look suggested code and code in the question are same, that should be `string format = "dd-MM-yyyy"`, @Adil: Now it is perfect after edit.. lol

Comment: thanks for correcting me about that format. But the problem is in parsing string value into Datetime. Why it is not converting into Datetime. I have date values into excel file like "24/11/2016" and i have to store it into sql database table like "2016-11-24".

Comment: @un-lucky, I already suggest dd-MM-yyyy, The statement you point was not suggested as correction although it looks like. Anyway thanks for letting me clear up the ambiguity!

Comment: SQL server storage of date is not irrespective of the presentation format the one you are trying i.e. dd-MM-yyyy, See this post, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143259/what-is-the-internal-representation-of-datetime-in-sql-server about the internal format of datetime. You can always format it before you present for instance on GUI.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i did it using the following code:

string format = "dd/MM/yy";

if (!DateTime.TryParseExact(date, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None,out dates))

{ continue; }

else

{ dates = DateTime.ParseExact(date, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); }

String datetime = dates.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");

*Thanks to all.*