# Default SQL Server Date Format

Tags: sql, sql-server

In SQL Server, a column with Date data type stores the date as: yyyy-MM-dd.
When selecting data from a column with Date data type using VB.NET it return that date as: MM/dd/yyyy.

How to tell SQL server to return the date as storder: yyyy-MM-dd. without converting the date to char in the select statement?

Comment: A `DATE` in SQL Server does **NOT** have any format - it's just a binary value. The formatting only happens when it's being output - so you **cannot** "store" a date in a "given format" - you can just make sure to **return it** in the desired format (by converting to a string, for instance)

Comment: Yes. Read the value from SQL Server as a DateTime, then use the ToString() method to format it how you like:  .ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")

Comment: Since SQL Server NOT have any format, how it distinguish between dd/MM/yyyy and MM/dd/yyyy?

Comment: Please see  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143259/what-is-the-internal-representation-of-datetime-in-sql-server    All localized formatting is in your own application code, not the server

Comment: If the date returned by a selected statement is 09/03/2020, then how to know that 09 is day or month?

Comment: You specify how to format the date in your code, like using `ToString("MM/dd/yyyy").

Answer (score 0):

```
select mmddyyyy = convert(varchar(10), getdate(), 101), yyyymmdd = convert(varchar(10), getdate(), 121)
```

[Use the convert function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)